# How to create a 2 value data table for keras

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to make my first neural network in keras (python) that takes in the x and y distances to the next pipe and outputs whether or not the bird should flap. How would I go about creating an input data set from the game and then turning that into something keras can use for training?

I don't have very much knowledge in this area and my high school computer science teachers don't know either, therefore I'm not quite sure where to start. I have a very, very basic understanding of Keras and NN concepts. I have tried using .csv files with pandas but I am not sure how to turn that into useable data.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: An array of shape `(examples, 2)`, where 2 goes for x and y, and another of shape `(examples, 1)` where 1 goes for one value, which is 0 for do nothing and 1 for flap?

Comment: @Worm I used this function: x = np.genfromtxt("input_data.txt", delimiter=',')  I now have a np array with size (100,2) there was 100 data sets. Is this what I need to plug into keras?

Answer (score 0):

Sir even i'm new to neural network  but i have some knowledge 
 if you want to do this in exactly this manner then i'm no help but
your can try doing this by genetic algo which will surely work for this

Comment: I'm not sure how to create or implement a genetic algo but if you have any pointers or a link to the code, it would be greatly appreciated.